# Не передаются имена файлов в bash для convert

Tags: linux, bash, скрипт, imagemagick

Задача. Есть сетевое файловое хранилище на Винде. В нём куча вложенных папок, в названиях возможно всё. В папках встречаются файлы картинок, которые нужно сконвертить в pdf. Что сделано: Смонтирован виндовый раздел. Подготовлен файл в котором построчно есть все файлы картинок для конвертации с полным путём по смонтированному разделу. Что пытаюсь: Пытаюсь через bash скрипт прочесть этот файл построчно и через convert сконвертировать картинки в pdf. Вот скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
while read -r LINE; do
        FLNAME=`basename "$LINE"`
        FLN=${FLNAME%%.*}
        FLE=${FLNAME##*.}
        FLP=${LINE%/*}
        echo $LINE  #эти echo просто для просмотра результата
        echo $FLNAME
        echo $FLN
        echo $FLE
        echo $FLP
        File1="$FLP/$FLN.$FLE"
        File2="$FLP/$FLN.pdf"
        echo $File1
        echo $File2
        convert "$File1" "$File2"
done < $FILE
IFS="$oldifs"
```

Файл приблизительно такого содержания:

```
/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.png
/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 210918 ТСО-1-80.jpg
...
```

Скрипт выдаёт ошибку:

```
srv/samba/srvdocs/topdf.sh /srv/samba/srvdocs/new3.txt
/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.png
ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.png
ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX
png
/srv/samba/srvdocs
/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.png
/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.pdf
': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2882.7 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.png
' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/564.image format `PNG
convert: no images defined `/srv/samba/srvdocs/ДС 230327 Эй энд Ди Влагомер весовой MF ML MS MX.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.
```

Уже устал перебирать варианты с кавычками, экранированием. Ничего не получается. Полагаю, что всё просто, но не могу понять.

Comment: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` попробуйте установить так `IFS="$(echo -en '\n\b')"`, только для меня не совсем понятно для чего так делать, неужели `IFS=$'\n'` не дает нужного результата? И насколько я помню, что бы вернуть IFS по умолчанию, достаточно просто отсоединить `unset IFS`

Comment: И кстати, если текстовый файл был создан на windows, то его следует проверить на наличие символов `\r` так как перевод строки в windows и linux отличаются, можно использовать команду `dos2linux` или к примеру `done< <(sed 's/\r//' $FILE)` для передачи обработанного текста сразу в цикл, без изменения в файле

Comment: Ну и плюс разбивка имени на части на мой взгляд напрасна в данном случае, почему просто не менять расширение файла "налету": `convert "${LINE}" "${LINE%.*}.png"`.

Comment: чтобы увидеть содержимое переменной побайтово: `echo -n "$var" | hexdump -C`. что-то мне подсказывает, что в конце имён файлов вы увидите `0d` (он же `\r`) — последствия использования в файле со списком [досовского разделителя строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перевод_строки). можно преобразовать файл, как выше подсказал PotroNik, а можно добавить команде *read* опцию `-d $'\r\n'`

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Да, так и есть. Везде 0d. Будем пробовать его его убирать.

Comment: @PotroNik Спасибо. Да именно в \r  мешал. Учёл и остальные рекомендации.

Comment: `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` вам нужен. @PotroNik к сведению (а не только переводы строк). И кстати это на порядок быстрее будет, чем `while read`.